# Show reCaptcha on Custom Frontend Login & Register Form

Tags: login, user-registration

using this tutorial

http://www.cozmoslabs.com/1012-wordpress-user-registration-template-and-custom-user-profile-fields

I have created custom login and register form for the frontend of my site, but, is there any way I can extend the forms to have recaptcha validation field.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you already customised the login and registration forms, just follow this [recaptcha customisation](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html) instruction, add the script and form element on your templates.

I believe you have to signup for a key to use recaptcha on your domain.

Comment: Is it possible to show recaptcha field by using wp-recaptcha plugin for wordpress on my custom login and register page??

Comment: I looked into wp-recaptcha. It writes the form on wordpress default registration form. So, you need to find the function within the plugin that renders the form and add the js, place that in your custom form. Easier if you just add your own by following recaptcha instruction.